# How can I sort an array with dictionarys? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

Let's say I have this array:

```js
[
  {num: 0, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 5, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 3, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 8, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 9, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 4, otherdatas: 'blah'}
]
```

And I want to sort this array. like this:

```js
[
  {num: 0, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 3, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 4, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 5, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 8, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 9, otherdatas: 'blah'}
]
```

If array was like `[0, 5, 3, 8, 9, 4]`, sorting would be easy, but I have these numbers on dictionary. What can I do for this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array and the array contains objects with two properties: num and otherdatas

- -use the sort method on the array
  -sort will accept two parameters,that point to the current and the next item in the array
  -u need to compare these two parameters with either a-b or b-a condition so as to get the result in ascending or descending order
  -make sure while comparing use a.num and b.num as the a and b here are not primitives but objects
  -a new array will be returned,store the array in some variable

```js
const arr1 = [
  {num: 0, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 5, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 3, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 8, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 9, otherdatas: 'blah'},
  {num: 4, otherdatas: 'blah'}
]

const sortedArr = arr1.sort(function(a,b){
return a.num - b.num;
//OR
// return b.num-a.num ;
})
```

Comment: You can use array function here

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.sort` accept an optional parameter called `compareFunction`, which is a function defining the sort order.

It should accept 2 parameters, a and b, the 2 elements to compare, and returns a number, indicating a < b if less than 0, a > b if greater than 0, and a = b if it is 0.

You can find it on MDN.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

you can sort your array using built in function sort

and the answer is

```
let tempData = data.sort((a,b) => (a.num > b.num) ? 1 : ((b.num > a.num) ? -1 : 0))
```

Output :

```
[
 {num: 0, otherdatas: 'blah'},
 {num: 3, otherdatas: 'blah'},
 {num: 4, otherdatas: 'blah'},
 {num: 5, otherdatas: 'blah'},
 {num: 8, otherdatas: 'blah'},
 {num: 9, otherdatas: 'blah'}
]
```